# Determine Websphere version dynamically during build time

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-7

I am working on a product which needs to be supported by different version of web-sphere(7.X,8.X and 9.X). I have to perform different build tasks(like copying different properties) based on WebSphere version. How can I determine the WebSphere version dynamically while running any build script.

Comment: is websphere really present when you build? Would it be preferrable to just always generate the different outputs?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the ability to run a script from your build environment, you can run the versionInfo.sh|bat file in the WAS_HOME/bin directory.  That'll provide way more information than you need, but you should be able to parse the output for the build level (in the output, it's labeled as "Version").